# using Rangeslider and trying to make it mobile compatible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, mobile

I am using [the Range slider plugin](https://api.jquerymobile.com/rangeslider/).

The plugin is working great -- it does exactly what it needs to on the computer, but when I try to use it on a mobile, the user can't drag the selector to where they desire..

Just like the Desktop, the user should be able to drag the handle where ever they want. Heres what i've tried:

```
var resStepValues = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 100, 120];
    jQuery("#slider_one").slider({
        animate: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 29,
        range: true,
        values: [displayLeft, displayRight],
        slide: .bind('mousemove touchmove', function (event, ui) {
            jQuery("#sliderone-min").text(numberWithCommas(resStepValues[ui.values[1]]));
            jQuery("#sliderone-max").text(numberWithCommas(resStepValues[ui.values[0]]));
        },
        change: .bind('mousemove touchmove', function(event, ui) {
            jQuery("input[name='priceFrom']").val(resStepValues[ui.values[0]]);
            jQuery("input[name='priceTo']").val(resStepValues[ui.values[1]]);
        }
    });
```

I added the .bind('mousemove touchmove', so hopefully when the user drags the selector it would work, but that is not working.. I was following this [guide](http://www.inserthtml.com/2013/01/touch-drag-movement-html5/) which has a simular concept.
Does anyone have any ideas? I am completely at loss on what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that's looking for the anwser to this, this is what you need.. Go here and download the file and include it into your site and it will work PERFECTLY..

http://touchpunch.furf.com/

Hopefully this helps someone out..